# take updated value of stepperLabel and multiply by value in array

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, multiplication, uistepper

```
class Service1ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var service1TableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var service1Total: UILabel!

    var Dry: [Service1] = []
    var orderCount = [Int : Int]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Dry = Options()
        for i in 0...30  // TotaL number of rows
        {
            orderCount[i] = 0 // DEFAULT order count will be 0
        }
    }

    func Options() -> [Service1]{
        var dryOptions: [Service1] = []

        let option1 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option2 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option3 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option4 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option5 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option6 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option7 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option8 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option9 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option10 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option11 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option12 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option13 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option14 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option15 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option16 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option17 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option18 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option19 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option20 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option21 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option22 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option23 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option24 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option25 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option26 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option27 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option28 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option29 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option30 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))
        let option31 = Service1(titled: "Test", pricing: Int(5.29), image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Test"))

        dryOptions.append(option1)
        dryOptions.append(option2)
        dryOptions.append(option3)
        dryOptions.append(option4)
        dryOptions.append(option5)
        dryOptions.append(option6)
        dryOptions.append(option7)
        dryOptions.append(option8)
        dryOptions.append(option9)
        dryOptions.append(option10)
        dryOptions.append(option11)
        dryOptions.append(option12)
        dryOptions.append(option13)
        dryOptions.append(option14)
        dryOptions.append(option15)
        dryOptions.append(option16)
        dryOptions.append(option17)
        dryOptions.append(option18)
        dryOptions.append(option19)
        dryOptions.append(option20)
        dryOptions.append(option21)
        dryOptions.append(option22)
        dryOptions.append(option23)
        dryOptions.append(option24)
        dryOptions.append(option25)
        dryOptions.append(option26)
        dryOptions.append(option27)
        dryOptions.append(option28)
        dryOptions.append(option29)
        dryOptions.append(option30)
        dryOptions.append(option31)

        return dryOptions
    }
}

extension Service1ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
    @IBAction func stepperAcn(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        print("sender.value         ", sender.value)
        let getTag : Int = sender.tag

        orderCount[getTag] = Int(sender.value)

        service1TableView.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 31
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let Dry1 = Dry[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Service1Cell") as! Service1TableViewCell
        cell.setService1(Dry: Dry1)
        cell.quantityStepper.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.stepperLabel.text = String(orderCount[indexPath.row]!) // PASS VALUES TO LABEL
        cell.quantityStepper.value = Double(orderCount[indexPath.row]!) // PASS VALUES TO STEPPER
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        func Total(){
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath.row)
            service1Total.text = cell.stepperLabel.value
        }
    }
}
```

I want to take the data from the updated value of the stepper label for all cells and multiply it by the specific cells pricing(located in function Options()) and print the results to service1Total. then in the function prepare for seague I want the cells with the stepper label value above 0 to move data to an alternate tableViewCell in another viewController along with moving the total data. this is the current code but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: Why do you have an unused nested function inside your `didSelectRowAt` function?

Comment: I was thinking to use didSelectRowAt to do the calculation but I don't know if thats correct or how to do it

Comment: Right but you have an used nested function in there named `Total`. That's unused code.

Comment: correct I can remove it though, the application runs I don't know how to get that function working though. I'm also having another issue with the stepper, when I select it in some of the cells the page scrolls up for some reason, any idea on how to fix that or should I start a new question.